# database data works fine on android 2.2 but not work on 2.3 higher

Tags: android, database, cursor, custom-adapter

i'm new here and new to android too...so i started to develop my first app for android...that load data from in a custom adapter...and when a try to retrieve data from my database, the rawquery that i use works fine just for android 2.2. Higher than 2.2 the cursor retrieves nothing. 
If i change the rawquery for query...it works only for 4.0 and for the versions below the cursor is empty. I noticed the problem is with the cursor.
Anyone know why that happens?

Method from main class

```
protected void selecionardados() {

// EditText to string
String busca = campo_busca.getText().toString();
//Open database class
Dados_banco consulta = new Dados_banco(this.getActivity());
consulta.open();
//Create a list
List<Dados_banco.ItemLista> itens = consulta.consultaMusica(busca);
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this.getActivity(),itens);
listagem.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Database method

```
public List<ItemLista> consultaMusica(String NovaPesquisa){
String r = NovaPesquisa;
List<ItemLista> itens = new ArrayList<Dados_banco.ItemLista>();
Cursor resul = bancodados.query(Tabela_musica, new String[] {"_id", "Musica","Cantor","letra_musica","cat_oracao","cat_missa"}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
for (resul.moveToFirst();!resul.isAfterLast();resul.moveToNext()) {
    Idlista = Integer.parseInt(resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("_id")));
    BdMusica = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("Musica"));
    BdCantor = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("Cantor"));
    BdLetra = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("letra_musica"));
    BdOracao = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("cat_oracao"));
    BdMissa = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("cat_missa"));

    itens.add(new ItemLista(){{

        id = Idlista;
        musica = BdMusica;
        cantor = BdCantor;
        letra = BdLetra;
        oracao = BdOracao;
        missa = BdMissa;
    });

}   resul.close();
    return itens;
```

CustomAdapter class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Dados_banco.ItemLista> itens;

public CustomAdapter(Activity a, List<Dados_banco.ItemLista> itens) {
    super();    
this.itens = itens;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)a.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return itens.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

Dados_banco.ItemLista item = itens.get(position);
View vi = convertView;

if(convertView==null){
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linha_listview, null);
    TextView id = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.linhaLista.id);
    TextView musica = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.linhaLista.musica);
    TextView artista = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.linhaLista.cantor);
    ImageView oracao = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.linhaLista.cat_oracao);
    ImageView missa = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.linhaLista.cat_missa);

    id.setText(String.valueOf(item.id));
    musica.setText(item.musica);
    artista.setText(item.cantor);
    String imgOra = item.oracao;
    String imgMissa = item.missa;

    if (imgOra.equals(null)) {
        oracao.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
    }else if(imgOra.equals("louvor")) {
        oracao.setImageResource(R.drawable.louvor);
        }else if(imgOra.equals("adoracao")) {
        oracao.setImageResource(R.drawable.adoracao);
    }

    if (imgMissa.equals(null)) {
            missa.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
    }else if(imgOra.equals("louvor")) {
        missa.setImageResource(R.drawable.louvor);
    }else if(imgOra.equals("adoracao")) {
        missa.setImageResource(R.drawable.adoracao);
    }

    }return vi;
}
}
```

Comment: What does the LogCat on 2.3 say?

Comment: Nothing. I used log.v in every line to find the error and an if/else in the cursor to see if it's working...and it doesn't return any data.

Comment: Go to window > show view > other > Android > LogCat and copy your LogCat

Comment: Nothing is showed on logCat...still blank. Just the Log.v that i used to verify if there is anything in the cursor is showed "if (cursor.getCount != 0){Log.v(" there's data",".")}else{Log.v("nothing inside",".")}.

Comment: Well..i found the error...the emulator create one database for each emulator, and the 2.3 was empty...i don't know why that happens but now it's ok. Thank Ahmad for try to help me.